# Why doesn't Java compiler find class from another file?

Tags: java, methods, subclass, extends

So, *Main.java* calls *class House* from *House.java*, one of the methods of *House.class* is supposed call a method from *class Appointment extends Succession*, which is located in *Succession.java*.

But for some reason, the compiler doesn't find `Appointment` and assumes it must be a missing variable, why? If I move the Appointment-class to Main.java or give it its own file, the compiler finds it.

I'm asking this because, I tried re-creating the error, by I haven't been able to...

House.java:

```
public void succession(){
    if (this.kinsmen.size() > 0){
        Appointment.callHeir(this.head, Main.human.get(1));
```

Succession.java:

```
class Appointment extends Succession {
    public static boolean callHeir(Human appointer, Human appointed){
```

Error:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
            Appointment.callHeir(this.head, Main.human.get(1));
            ^
  symbol:   variable Appointment
  location: class House
```

Edit full code minimized:

Main.java:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        House.succession();
    }
}
```

House.java:

```
public class House {
    public static void succession() {
        Appointment.callHeir();
    }
}
```

Succession.java:

```
class Succession{

}

class Appointment extends Succession {
    public static void callHeir(){
    }
}
```

Comment: a missing dependency, a missing import ... the description is to vague to be sure

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Wild guess: the missing class is not on the classpath, so check where it is (directory or jar) and put that onto the classpath.

Comment: Make Appointment public perhaps?

Comment: Another wild guess: class Appointment is not public so package-private. Maybe House is located in another package.

Comment: Or you're compiling from the wrong directory, in a way that means the compiler is looking in the wrong place for the source code. But again, we need to know how you're compiling in order to reproduce that.

Comment: As @JoakimDanielson says but in that case Appointment must be within a separate file (a single file can contain only 1 public class).

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm compiling it via Atom.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend compiling it from the command line so you can get *that* much working, and then try to work out how to get Atom to compile in the same way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Compiling it from Terminal gives the same error.

Comment: Right, so please show in your question (not in comments) a *complete* example - complete (but minimal) source code, and *exactly* how you're compiling it, including where you're compiling it from with relation to where the source files are.

Comment: @RobertKock As I said, if I give it its own file, it works, but I was asking why does such error occur here, but in other similar cases.

Comment: The error message implies a missing dependency, but on a side note: Appointment is a package private class and thus cannot be seen from other packages. In case you'll run into more problems later.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure how I further the example; all the files are in the same folder.

Comment: But we don't know whether there's a package declaration, we don't know what command line you're running to try to compile. To put it another way: the only code you've provided is part of a class declaration and one method. That isn't enough for us to try to reproduce the problem. I could put those bits of code into files with appropriate package declarations, folders matching the package declarations, and compile the right way from the right place, and not see the error you've seen. But because we don't know what *you're* doing, we don't know which bit is causing the problem.

Comment: So you say that all classes (Main, House and Succession) are in the same package?

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, it's very hard for us to find what the error is without a complete example. Another wild guess: Did you define Appointment as an inner class of Succession?

Comment: I compile with standard javac-command. I have added a complete example. And yes, they are in the same package.

Comment: "I compile with standard javac-command" - but you haven't shown us what that is! I've just copied all of your code and run `javac *.java` and it compiled without any issues. So presumably that's not what you're doing.

Comment: My *guess* is that you're just running `javac Main.java`, but *we don't know that because you haven't told us*. As an aside, I would strongly recommend that you *do* put `Appointment.java` in its own file - I would generally suggest putting each top-level class in its own file, to make it easier for *humans* to find it, let alone the compiler.

Comment: When launching `javac Main.java` it get the error but only if I don't compile Succession.java first. Calling `javac *.java` compiles correctly. Interesting!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but this might be the reason:

When compiling `Main.java` it encounters `House.succession()`.
It doesn't find `House.class` so it looks for and compiles `House.java`.

When compiling `House.java` it encounters `Appointment.callHeir()`.
It doesn't find `Appointment.class` so it looks for `Appointment.java` which doesn't exist.

When I change `House.java` like this

```
public class House {
    public static void succession() {
        Succession dummy;
        Appointment.callHeir();
    }
}
```

everything works fine.
This because it encounters `Succession dummy` first which makes the compiler look for `Succession.java`. Compiling that file, we automatically obtain `Appointment.class`.

As already suggested by others, I strongly recommend to put the `Appointment` class in its own file.

Comment: I'd also recommend always compiling *all* the code, rather than just an entry point - otherwise it's easy to end up with inconsistent code.

Comment: Thanks, dude! I was going to give it its own file regardless but just I was curious about why this occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Set Access Modifier/specifier of Appointment class as `public`.
Because by default access modifier/specifier  of any class is `default` which doesnot allow access the class from another class.

Make Sure if you need to access the class from outside the class the access modifier/specifier  of class will be public.

Comment: "Because by default access modifier/specifier of any class is default which doesnot allow access the class from another class." Yes it does, if the classes are in the same package. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6: "A top level class or interface type declared without an access modifier implicitly has package access." and "If a top level class or interface type is declared with package access, then it may be accessed only from within the package in which it is declared."

Comment: I got your point. I try to explain my answer briefly. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I'm not seeing any change in the answer. Basically, the problem is *not* because of the access modifier.